# POST or AJAX display one form or the other (Login or Register) by button click that is loaded from a single file

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have an account page which displays two buttons. Login and Register.
When the user clicks one I would like it to load my accForm.php and generate a form for the button clicked.
Here is my code so far:

main.php

```
<div id="main">
  <h1 id="center">Account</h1>
  <form action="accForm.php" method="POST"
    <button type="button" id="login">Login</button>
    <button type="button" id="register">Register</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

accForm.php

```
$content = "";
if (isset($_POST["login"])) {
$content = <<<HTML
 <form id="formLogin" method="POST">
     <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>
     <label for="pin"><b>PIN</b></label>
     <input type="text" name="pin" pattern="[0-9]{4}" maxlength="4">
     <input type="submit" value="Login">
 </form>
HTML;
} else {
 //Assume Register
 $content = <<<HTML
 <form id="frmReg" method="POST">
     <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>
     <label for="email"><b>eMail Address</b></label>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Enter eMail Address" name="email" required>
     <label for="pin"><b>PIN</b></label>
     <input type="text" name="pin" pattern="[0-9]{4}" maxlength="4">
     <label class="screen-reader-only" for="choice">Yes or No?</label>
     <span aria-hidden="true">No</span>
     <input type="range" max="1" id="choice" name="choice">
     <span aria-hidden="true">Yes</span>    
     <input type="submit" value="Register">
 </form>
 HTML;

}
echo $content;
?>
```

I'm trying to get the form to load either below the login and register buttons for now or preferably replace them but I just can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: You forgot to set `name` attributes on your buttons

Comment: Your form opening tag needs to be closed `<form ... >`

Comment: And also these buttons will not submit the form. They need to be `type="submit"`

Comment: thank you it was the type="submit" I was missing. As well as adding the name attributes

Comment: However it does not stay on the main page is this possible?

Comment: For that you would need to use JavaScript and Ajax to submit the form, get the html back from the server and insert it into the page

Comment: Or, make the form action blank and move your processing logic into main.php directly above your main form.

Comment: Okay thank you, I will give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

main.php

````
```<div id="main">
    <h1 id="center">Account</h1>
    <form action="accForm.php" method="POST"
      <button type="button" id="login">Login</button>
      <button type="button" id="register">Register</button>
    </form>
   </div>```
````

to

```
<div id="main">
<h1 id="center">Account</h1>
<form action="accForm.php" method="POST">
 <button type="submit" name="login" id="login">Login</button>
 <button type="submit" name="login" id="register">Register</button>
</form>
</div>
```